# Android Keyboard Lag Animation

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, android-keypad

On one of my activities i have an edit box that of course when clicked opens up the keyboard. However, even though the keyboard does animate there seems to be a strange lag of the editbox moving up? Ive tried a few different things however to no avail.

Below is my activity and xml files.

**ACTIVITY**

```
private TextView countText;
private ListView listView;
private ArrayList<MessagingObject> arrayList;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_messaging_page);

    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messagingList);
    counttext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.characterCount);
    counttext.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    final Button sendMessage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendMessage_button);
    EditText message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message_textbox);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");


    message.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.length() > 20){
                sendMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                counttext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                String textOver = new String().valueOf(s.length() - 20);
                counttext.setText("-"+textOver+"");
            } else {
                sendMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                counttext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

    startTimer();
    arrayList = new ArrayList<MessagingObject>();
    getActionBar().setTitle(name);
}
```

**XML DOCUMENT**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f6f6f6">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/messagingList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/messageheaderbottom_layout"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="30.0sp"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:background="#f6f6f6"
    android:overScrollMode="never">
</ListView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/messageheaderbottom_layout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#DEDEDE">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message_textbox"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/textfield_rounded"
        android:hint="Message"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:maxLength="140"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendMessage_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/message_textbox"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Send"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#344294"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/characterCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/message_textbox"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#000"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any suggestions or solutions would be great. Thanks.